# Cannot recycle app pool remotely from IIS

Tags: c#, iis

As I have seen recommended, I am using the `Microsoft.web.administration` library, specifically the `ServerManager.OpenRemote()` and `manager.ApplicationPools[poolName]` code to try and recycle a remote application pool. My code is

```
var managerTwo = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverTwo);
var testPoolTwo = managerTwo.ApplicationPools[testPoolName];
```

However I get the error

> {"Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine wycvwwebd017
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154 wycvwwebd017."}

It seems this error means that it cannot find the class to load. I have checked in the registry on the remote machine and the clsid definitely exists. Any idea how to troubleshoot why COM cannot find the clsid?

Comment: Access denied. Permissions issue.

Comment: Do you know how I assign my IIS server account permissions so I can recycle it remotely?

Comment: So you want to access the IIS Administration API on machine X from a web application running in IIS on machine Y? I wouldn't want to, because that would give the application pool on machine Y way too many permissions.

Comment: I have a load balanced setup with two servers running a website. When a user uploads a new code version to the web site, the web api deploys the new codebase, which then requires an app pool recycle to work. because there are two servers, each server cannot just recycle itself as the other server will not be recycled and 50% of the time the users will get a failed operation, so both need to be recycled when you upload to either one. I don't see any other way of doing it